# Postgres ERROR : FOR Update must specify unqualified relation names

Tags: postgresql, function, plpgsql

i`m getting an error when i run the following postgres function.Error is on line 9 on SQL statement. The error looks to be after 'FOR UPDATE OF TSN."SN_SEQUENCE_NUMBER";'. Maybe it is something trivial, but i'm a newbie in a postgres and functions.
I tried many things for example :

1. Remain only the "SN_SEQUENCE_NUMER"
2. Remain only the TSN or try with the full name of the table

Code:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION dev_web.get_next_sequence_number(in_sn_stream character varying, in_sn_reference character varying, in_sn_serverhost character varying, in_sn_date character, in_sn_reset character varying)
    RETURNS integer
    LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS $function$

DECLARE
   NEXT_SEQ_NUM INTEGER;
   CURRENT_SEQUENCE_DATE character(8);
   SEQUENCE_RESET numeric;

BEGIN

   LOCK TABLE "TB_SEQUENCE_NUMBERS"  IN EXCLUSIVE MODE;

    SELECT "SN_SEQUENCE_NUMBER", "SN_DATE", "SN_RESET"
    INTO NEXT_SEQ_NUM, CURRENT_SEQUENCE_DATE, SEQUENCE_RESET
    FROM "TB_SEQUENCE_NUMBERS" TSN
    WHERE TSN."SN_STREAM" = GET_NEXT_SEQUENCE_NUMBER.IN_SN_STREAM AND TSN."SN_REFERENCE" = GET_NEXT_SEQUENCE_NUMBER.IN_SN_REFERENCE
    FOR UPDATE OF TSN."SN_SEQUENCE_NUMBER";
    

IF NOT FOUND THEN
    INSERT INTO "TB_SEQUENCE_NUMBERS" ("SN_STREAM", "SN_REFERENCE", "SN_UPDATED_BY", "SN_DATE", "SN_SEQUENCE_NUMBER", "SN_RESET")
    VALUES (GET_NEXT_SEQUENCE_NUMBER.IN_SN_STREAM, GET_NEXT_SEQUENCE_NUMBER.IN_SN_REFERENCE, GET_NEXT_SEQUENCE_NUMBER.IN_SN_SERVERHOST, GET_NEXT_SEQUENCE_NUMBER.IN_SN_DATE, 1, GET_NEXT_SEQUENCE_NUMBER.IN_SN_RESET)
    RETURNING 1 INTO NEXT_SEQ_NUM;

    COMMIT;
    RETURN NEXT_SEQ_NUM;

ELSE
    IF UPPER(SEQUENCE_RESET) = 'DAILY' THEN
        IF GET_NEXT_SEQUENCE_NUMBER.IN_SN_DATE = CURRENT_SEQUENCE_DATE THEN
            NEXT_SEQ_NUM := NEXT_SEQ_NUM + 1;
        ELSE
            NEXT_SEQ_NUM := 1;
            CURRENT_SEQUENCE_DATE := GET_NEXT_SEQUENCE_NUMBER.IN_SN_DATE;
        END IF;

    ELSE
        NEXT_SEQ_NUM := NEXT_SEQ_NUM + 1;
    END IF;
    
    UPDATE "TB_SEQUENCE_NUMBERS" TSN
    SET SN_SEQUENCE_NUMBER = NEXT_SEQ_NUM,
        SN_REFERENCE = GET_NEXT_SEQUENCE_NUMBER.IN_SN_REFERENCE,
        SN_DATE = CURRENT_SEQUENCE_DATE,
        SN_STREAM = GET_NEXT_SEQUENCE_NUMBER.IN_SN_STREAM,
        SN_UPDATED_BY = GET_NEXT_SEQUENCE_NUMBER.IN_SN_SERVERHOST
    WHERE CURRENT OF c1;

    COMMIT;
END IF;

    RETURN NEXT_SEQ_NUM;
END;

$function$
;
```

Comment: Leave the FOR UPDATE out, you already locked the entire table. And you can't use COMMIT in a function.

Comment: PostgreSQL already has [Sequences](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createsequence.html) so there's no need for a `TB_SEQUENCE_NUMBERS` table. Locking is almost always wrong. In this case, a single UPDATE can be used to increment the desired field *and* return the new values by adding a [RETURNING clause](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/dml-returning.html) to UPDATE. The same works in other database with different syntax (except MySQL, which doesn't have SEQUENCE either)

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos  OP does need the table. It seems this is a case of unfortunate object naming. The function is apparently maintaining many "sequences"; 1 for each value of parameter  `in_sn_stream` and some only updates once a day.  Although I tend question the need for maintaining multiple as you are correct a single Postgres managed sequence might be a better choice.